# Why when I use @PostMapping is the result correct, and when I replace it with @RequestMapping the result is a 404 HTTP error？

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The code is here:

```java
@ResponseBody
//@RequestMapping(name = "getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PostMapping("getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity")
public PageResult getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity(@RequestBody HipJointVo hipJointVo) {
    return hipJointScreenService.getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity(hipJointVo);
}
```

When I request this API which uses `PostMapping` annotation, the result code is ok and nothing is wrong, but when I replace the annotation
`@PostMapping("getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity")` with `@RequestMapping(name = "getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity",method = RequestMethod.POST)`, the HTTP request code is 404.

The requestBody has no changes. All the data is exactly the same.

And this is how I do the post request in postman

[image: and this is how I do the post request in postman]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using the `name` parameter of `@RequestMapping`, which isn't what you're intending. Instead, you should use `value` (which is the default parameter the value is applied to if you don't specify, as in your `@PostMapping` version) or `path` (which is a Spring alias to make the code more readable).

Comment: @berry If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark in the margin.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping` and `@PostMapping`'s default parameter is `value` and `value` is aliasFor `path`. Both parameter are for path mapping.

`@PostMapping("getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity")` ==
`@RequestMapping(value = "getScreenRecordListByHipJointEntity", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html